# Spring Bean not created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've constructed a Spring-Boot-Application, which is using `ComponentScan` to identify the Spring beans. Upon start of the application I get the message

```
Parameter <X> of constructor in <BEANUSER> required a bean of type '<BEAN>' that could not be found.
```

In the same package, where I defined `<BEAN>` there are several other Spring beans which can all be found and injected. However, the constructor of `BEAN` is never called. The simple name of `BEAN` is `TransactionManager`.

I have checked all annotations and they are similar to the beans working.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot will - by default - generate a bunch of so calles implicit spring-beans. The beans created depends on the libraries found on the classpath. If the classpath contains spring-boot-starter-jdbc it will lead to the creation of a Spring-Transactionmanager (as an implicit bean).

While this class has most probably a different package-name and cannot be substituted for injection, there is a clash in the name of the beans (which are by default only composed of the simple name of the bean-class). This leads to Spring completely ignoring the user-defined class.

Rename your `TransactionManager` to something else and everything should be fine.